# Ubuntuで apt update をしようとするとエラーになってしまい解決出来ない

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, apt, wsl-2

タイトルの通りですが，`sudo apt update` が出来なくなりました．
以下のエラーが表示され解決できません．

apt update 実行時のエラー

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:2 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease [2895 B]
Err:2 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 6DB5542C356545CF Heroku, Inc. <support@heroku.com>
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 6DB5542C356545CF Heroku, Inc. <support@heroku.com>
E: The repository 'https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

以前も似たようなことはあったのですが，その際は”パブリックキーがなんちゃら”という文言だったのですが，今回はそのような文言が出てきていません．

調べてみても，同じように躓いている人は以前の僕と同じ，パブリックキー関連の人しか見つけられていないので，どなたかわかる方がいましたら，アドバイスをください．

追記

コメントくださいました皆様，ありがとうございます！
しばらく時間を置いて，先程もう一度やってみたら，今度は以下のようになりました．
改めて，同じ内容で質問させていただきたいです，よろしくお願いします．

```
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Get:1 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease [2550 B]
Get:2 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease [2550 B]
Err:1 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 536F8F1DE80F6A35
Err:2 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 536F8F1DE80F6A35
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 536F8F1DE80F6A35
E: The repository 'https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 536F8F1DE80F6A35
```

最終追記

質問に回答くださった皆様ありがとうございました．
今のところまだ状況が変わらないので，新たな質問も立てず静観しようと思います．
また立てたらお願いします．

Comment: エラーの内容が変わって質問内容も変わっているため、一旦こちらは解決ということにして、追記部分については別の質問として新しくご投稿いただけないでしょうか。そうするとそれぞれの内容が Q&A として見やすくなります。

Comment: 単に「エラーになった」じゃなく、「どんなエラーメッセージが出たのか」に注目し、調べたり質問を組み立ててみてください。

Comment: お二方，ありがとうございます．　改めて質問を立てさせていただきますので，その際には知恵をお借りできたら嬉しいです．スタックオーバーフローも含めて勉強中ですので頑張ります！

Answer (score 3, accepted):

実際としては「正解は "待つ"」である点は他の方と同じ話ですが、一応。

```
Err:2 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 6DB5542C356545CF Heroku, Inc. <support@heroku.com>
...
W: GPG error: https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 6DB5542C356545CF Heroku, Inc. <support@heroku.com>
```

Err:2 で報告されているエラーメッセージ、そしてパッケージ一覧読み込み後のメッセージを見る限り、こちらのリポジトリーにある GPG 鍵の署名が有効期間切れ (expired key signature) であるため、適切なリポジトリーである事を確認できていない状態です。
このため、「Heroku 側が鍵を更新して登録するしなおすまで待つ」のが正解、という感じでしょうか。

理由が理由ですし、投稿日時的に、なんとなく既に解決してそうな気もしますが。

Answer (score 2):

`heroku.com` サーバ側の障害だと思われますので、ユーザーである我々にできることは何もありません。あわてず騒がず復旧を待ちましょう。

Answer (score 2):

cli-assets.heroku.com のリポジトリー内のパッケージに更新があるか調べるのに失敗したようです (アクセスしたら 404 だし) 。
サイトが復旧するの待つか, 一時的にその行を無効化して更新行うとか？ でしょうか

無効化するなら, GUIツールが用意されているならそれで
ツールがなくともテキストエディターで編集可能 (バックアップ取るとよい)

ただし, 理解せずに編集行うと余計沼にはまるので, オススメは「待つ」です

```
$ ls -l /etc/apt/sources.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 /etc/apt/sources.list

/etc/apt/sources.list.d:
  *.list
```

---

#### 追記

例えば次の行は, リポジトリーから `InRelease`を取得するもの。

```
https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease
```

Ubuntuは Debian系で, Debianに詳しい資料載ってることがあります。
[Debian Repository Format](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format)

これによると, `"dists/$DIST/InRelease"` ==> https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt/dists/InRelease

ここが **404 Not Found** のままだと, ファイルが取得できず 検証できない